# How to use French Accented Characters in PDFLib 7?

Tags: pdf-generation

I am using PDFLib 7 to generate mailing labels. I am having issues displaying French accented characters. For example, **Maître Corbeau** is displayed as **MaÃ®tre Corbeau**. Similarly, **SadÖ** is displayed as **SADÃ**.

The simplified code that I am using is like this:

```
 $pdfDoc = new PDFlib();
 $pdfDoc->set_info("Creator", "Kits Communications");
// more document info settings
 $pdfDoc->begin_page_ext($PageWidth, $PageHeight, "");
 $font = $pdfDoc->load_font("Helvetica", "auto", "");
 $pdfDoc->setfont($font, 9.0);
 // get data in variables 
 $pdfDoc->show(strtoupper($NameLine1));
 $pdfDoc->continue_text($AddressLine1);
```

If I display the contents on the page with echo, the string is displayed correctly. I believe that perhaps I need to define default character set to PDFLib. Could someone please advise the required command to be used for PDFLib 7?

Answer (score 0):

The text I was writing into a PDFLib document is in UTF-8 format. If I send the text in ANSI format, the mailing labels appear correctly. I added the following command to convert text to the ANSI format.

```
$NameLine1 = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252",$NameLine1);
```

This fixed the issue on Windows PC. Not tested on Mac.